# meteor unable to resolve some modules

Tags: javascript, meteor, package

I am using meteor after installing the following packages, `stylus`, `pward123:rupture` & `mquandalle:jeet` I get the following errors. I tried running `meteor npm install --save @babel/runtime` as suggested but it didn't do anything. Here is the errors I am getting when trying to run meteor.

```
Unable to resolve some modules:

  "@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault" in /C/Users/Anders/sites/jlfitsiteDevelopment/client/lib/modernizr-custom.js (web.browser.legacy)
  "@babel/runtime/helpers/typeof" in /C/Users/Anders/sites/jlfitsiteDevelopment/client/lib/modernizr-custom.js (web.browser.legacy)

If you notice problems related to these missing modules, consider running:

  meteor npm install --save @babel/runtime

W20180622-17:28:30.133(-6)? (STDERR) C:\Users\Anders\sites\jlfitsiteDevelopment\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:475
W20180622-17:28:30.134(-6)? (STDERR) }).run();
W20180622-17:28:30.134(-6)? (STDERR)    ^
W20180622-17:28:30.135(-6)? (STDERR)
W20180622-17:28:30.135(-6)? (STDERR) Error: The @babel/runtime npm package could not be found in your node_modules
W20180622-17:28:30.136(-6)? (STDERR) directory. Please run the following command to install it:
W20180622-17:28:30.136(-6)? (STDERR)
W20180622-17:28:30.136(-6)? (STDERR)   meteor npm install --save @babel/runtime
W20180622-17:28:30.136(-6)? (STDERR)
W20180622-17:28:30.137(-6)? (STDERR)     at babel-runtime.js (packages\babel-runtime.js:25:9)
W20180622-17:28:30.137(-6)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages\modules-runtime.js:339:7)
W20180622-17:28:30.137(-6)? (STDERR)     at require (packages\modules-runtime.js:238:16)
W20180622-17:28:30.137(-6)? (STDERR)     at packages\babel-runtime.js:79:15
W20180622-17:28:30.138(-6)? (STDERR)     at packages\babel-runtime.js:86:3
W20180622-17:28:30.138(-6)? (STDERR)     at C:\Users\Anders\sites\jlfitsiteDevelopment\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:411:36
W20180622-17:28:30.138(-6)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
W20180622-17:28:30.139(-6)? (STDERR)     at C:\Users\Anders\sites\jlfitsiteDevelopment\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:220:19
W20180622-17:28:30.139(-6)? (STDERR)     at C:\Users\Anders\sites\jlfitsiteDevelopment\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:471:5
W20180622-17:28:30.139(-6)? (STDERR)     at Function.run (C:\Users\Anders\sites\jlfitsiteDevelopment\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\profile.js:510:12)
```

.meteor/packages

```
mongo@1.5.0                   # The database Meteor supports right now
blaze-html-templates    # Compile .html files into Meteor Blaze views
session@1.1.7                 # Client-side reactive dictionary for your app
jquery                  # Helpful client-side library
tracker@1.2.0                 # Meteor's client-side reactive programming library

standard-minifiers@1.1.0      # JS/CSS minifiers run for production mode
es5-shim@4.8.0                # ECMAScript 5 compatibility for older browsers.
ecmascript@0.11.1              # Enable ECMAScript2015+ syntax in app code

autopublish@1.0.7             # Publish all data to the clients (for prototyping)
insecure@1.0.7                # Allow all DB writes from clients (for prototyping)
iron:router
sewdn:masked-input
themeteorchef:jquery-validation
email@1.2.3
johannesma:meteor-flexslider
slam310:smooth-scroll
underscore
stylus
mquandalle:jeet
pward123:rupture
```

Comment: From what I can see in the question, running `meteor npm install --save @babel/runtime` should be the correct solution. Have you also tried a `meteor reset` and deleting node_modules and running `meteor npm install` again?

Comment: Please also add your `package.json` and `.meteor/packages` content to make this reproducible.

Comment: @FredStark I have run `meteor npm install --save @babel/runtime` twice now, I have ran `meteor rest` still with the same result. I don't see a node_modules folder anywhere so still very stuck.

Comment: @Jankapunkt I have added my `.meteor/packages` file but I don't see a package.json file anywhere to add?

Comment: If there's no package.json or node_modules directory that's definitely your issue! I'll add detail on how to replace it in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no `package.json` or `node_modules` directory that's definitely your issue!

There should be a package.json at the root of your project at:

```
C:\Users\Anders\sites\jlfitsiteDevelopment\
```

You can probably safely copy the package json from a fresh `meteor create`:

```
{
  "name": "~name~",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run",
    "test": "meteor test --once --driver-package meteortesting:mocha",
    "test-app": "TEST_WATCH=1 meteor test --full-app --driver-package meteortesting:mocha",
    "visualize": "meteor --production --extra-packages bundle-visualizer"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "^0.4.1"
  }
}
```

And then add any extra dependencies you require

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps someone else: The above answer didn't apply to me. I had ran `npm install` to initialize the directory but I was having problems with my version of 
`babel/runtime` not working as soon as I updated to Meteor 1.7.x

I downgraded the version of babel by running the following command:
`meteor npm install --save-exact @babel/runtime@7.0.0-beta.55`